# Best way to display warning message to "untested" browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have an app that I have fully tested in Safari 5, IE 9, FF6, and Chrome 14.  I'm not looking to block or exclude any browsers from the experience.  But I want to warn/inform users that there may be a better experience in another browser, and if they choose to continue, there may be features not working or broken.

I have looked at jQuery browser detection, but it seems to be a bit quirky.  I know the best solution would be to warn based on feature detection, but we are currently in beta and I am not completely sure what features make or break.  Such as web workers, its known that web workers not working breaks our app, but it works in IE lower versions.  But then there is an issue with Opera that web workers is available, but not functioning correctly.

Ultimately I am looking for an easy way to say Browser X Version y and up don't show warning, and those and under show warning.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: what is the issue with Opera and Web Workers? is it a known problem with the browser in general or something that is specific to your site?

Comment: I am depending on a bunch of different libraries, and one utilizes web workers, which works find, however one of the physics libraries has an issue in Opera.

Comment: I have found a useful jquery library that already parses user-agents, etc.  It may be my solution, but I'd like to see what else there is.

Comment: Beware of user agent strings. they can be spoofed or rendered inaccurate. (having said that, they're more likely to be accurate if you read them on the client itself, and if someone is spoofing their browser UA string to fool you, it's their own fault if something breaks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser detection is indeed "a bit quirky", in pretty much any scenario. The jQuery route is probably as good as you're going to get, but as you say it's not great.

A better solution is generally to do feature detection, especially in cases like the one you describe where your site relies on specific features.

The best feature detection library is [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/). This will give you an bunch of Javascript flags which are set to true or false according to whether the browser supports a given feature. It detects support for a whole bunch of stuff, including Web Workers.

Comment: I actually just stumbled upon this old gem, it may be my answer. http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/

Modernizr is also a great solution, thanks Spudley.

Comment: I am trying to avoid feature detection as features are being changed often, and I am not 100% what features are not working and are working.

Comment: IME Feature detection can pick up what APIs are available - but that's NOT the same thing as the API working consistently across all browsers which claim to support it - I'd recommend only using feature detection to highlight where you know it won't work, and to determine the visual impact of any user messages.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

-Easy way of detecting the user's browser with javascript.  From there I'd just use a switch statement or something to display the messages for browsers that aren't tested yet.  If you want the exact browser version you'll have to parse it from the "navigator.userAgent" field.

Comment: w3schools.com is [not](http://w3fools.com/) generally considered the best resource, plus OP is more targeting on feature detection rather than user-agent detection (which is unreliable as it can be spoofed).

Comment: While this would work, I was curious to see if there was anything better than this approach, or something someone else has already done to solve this problem.

Comment: you should also detect for supported browser features like eg `function supports_webworkers() { return !! window.Worker; }`

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is full validation, you need to be even more specific about versions. Keep in mind that some browser upgrades are not 100% backwards compatible with previous versions. (Look at how IE8 mode in IE9 is not the same as native IE8 rendering, for instance.) You're going to have to retest with every new browser version, and sooner or later there's going to be a "Fully tested with browser version X, not tested with version X+1 that was released yesterday" problem. Feature detection, graceful degradation, and a warning non-intrusively displayed to the user if their experience is being significantly downgraded is a better way to go.

To directly answer your question, if you must implement what you are asking for just parse the user agent. This could be useful specifically watching out for a browser you know doesn't work right and warning, or as a bandaid for a badly written intranet app that is very picky about the exact browser version it will run on. For a newly developed app where you have control over the requirements, I would not recommend warning on browser version since there are better ways to do it.

Comment: While I am trying to avoid the whole issue with browsers on the internet.  As an Avid Opera user, I understand what you are saying.  

I am trying to avoid the whole browser warning situation, but we are in beta and just need a quick information on that we may not have your browser working 100%.